# Storing variables in specific addresses in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-address

I have an assignment that asks me to make a Fibonacci loop and store the first 10 numbers in the memory from address 200 hexadecimal and so forth.
I am using DOSBox 0.74 for this. I know how to do the Fibonacci loop I just don't get how I can store the numbers in that very specific address. Should I make an array sized 10 and store it there as an array or is it possible to store as 10 different number? What commands do I need to use to store it and how can I find a specific address when needed to?

For example 13 in hexadecimal.

Comment: You should mention which assembler you're using, the answer varies a fair a bit depending on whether you're using MASM, NASM, the GNU assembler or something else.

Comment: ummm genuinely i have no idea, i do use dosbox but have no clue which assembler it has

Comment: DOSBox doesn't come with an assembler. What command to do you type to run the assembler?

Comment: i compiled the code and ran it through turbo debugger, somewhere in the process i saw NASM, the commands `mov [0200h], ax`
`mov [0202h], ax` worked for me

Comment: Yah, that's NASM syntax. It wouldn't work with MASM or the GNU assembler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *address* is an offset in a memory segment.

Use instructions like the following if the segment is addressable through the DS segment register.

```
mov [0200h], ax
mov [0202h], ax
```

Add a segment override prefix is the segment is addressable through ES.

```
mov [es:0200h], ax
mov [es:0202h], ax
```

Depending on your assembler you might need to use *word ptr* or move the segment override prefix outside the brackets.